# How to handle hive and hbase integration which contains complex type: map and array

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, hbase, impala

I would like to integrate hive and Hbase and query data from impala via hive metadata.

hbase version: 1.2.0-cdh5.14.2
hive version:  1.1.0-cdh5.14.2
impala version: 2.11.0--cdh5.14.2

In the HBase table, there is only one column family and there are some columns in the column family which contains string type, int type and some complex type, such as map and array. As for the complex type, such as map and array, I just generate map and array in business code and serialize them to byte array and write the byte array to hbase.

When I create an external hive table to interrelate the hbase table as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE external_facttable_testmap (
        key string,
        user_id string,
        event_time string,
        device_preference_value map<string,int>,
        device_preference array<string>,
        active_day_value map<string,int>,
        active_day array<string>,
        active_time_value map<string,int>,
        active_time array<string>,
        daily_order_num bigint,
        daily_mall_order_num bigint,
        daily_promoted_order_num bigint,
        daily_gmv bigint,
        daily_promoted_value bigint,
        rating_record_value string,
        average_rating_record array<string>,
        payment_method_preference_value map<string,int>,
        payment_method_preference array<string>,
        logistics_method_preference_value map<string,int>,
        logistics_method_preference array<string>,
        category_preference_value map<string,int>,
        category_preference array<string>,
        subcategory_preference_value map<string,int>,
        subcategory_preference array<string>)
      ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe'
      STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
      WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
        "hbase.columns.mapping" =
   ":key,default:user_id,default:event_time,default:device_preference_value,default:device_preference,default:active_day_value,default:active_day,
          default:active_time_value,default:active_time,default:daily_order_num,default:daily_mall_order_num,default:daily_promoted_order_num,default:daily_gmv,
          default:daily_promoted_value,default:rating_record_value,default:average_rating_record,default:payment_method_preference_value,
          default:payment_method_preference,default:logistics_method_preference_value,default:logistics_method_preference,default:category_preference_value,
          default:category_preference,default:subcategory_preference_value,default:subcategory_preference"
      )
      TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "facttable");
```

And I have no idea about the complex type, Can it support the complex type to handle hive and hbase integration?

Thanks.